# OCR - most "different" or "recognizable" ASCII characters?

Tags: image-processing, theory, ocr, computer-vision

I am looking for a way to determine the most "different" or "recognizable" N ASCII characters...  For example, if N = 10, what would be the most different N characters in the ASCII set from 0x21 to 0x7E?  Obviously, the character "X" is very different than "O" (the letter), but "O" (the letter) is very similar to "0" (zero).  Assuming a restricted OCR character subset, such that zero and the letter O would be detected as one or the other only, and one didn't have to worry about whether it was a zero or a letter O, what would be the most different N characters that typical OCR engines (for example Tesseract) recognize easily from a poor quality input image?  Assumptions. such as "+" and "t" could widely be mistaken for one another. can be made, and thus each input character, whether it's "+" or "t" would only correspond to one or the other.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: I think the choice of characters would depend on the method used to recognize them.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Actually, I think that this would depend more on FONT than anything else...

Comment: It's also not terribly useful to ask the question for single individual letters, as OCR errors often confuse "d" with "cl", "m" with "rn", etc.

Comment: Brian: Granted, it does depend on the font a great deal.

Amuck: I am curious about it, and have wondered about it for a long time (basically after seeing an extended ASCII set with some of the characters labeled "ocr") , it's more of a theoretical question.

Comment: Depends on your application's needs. Are you trying to come up with something that can be printed to a sheet of paper and is easily readable by both computers and humans? Text with Braille-esque dots below each character comes to mind for some odd reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there will be a single unique answer for this.

It'll depend on the font: Compare the different ways that 0, f, s are represented and also stylistic flourishes.

It'll depend on the type of damage the characters receive before being scanned, some may be more resilient against smudging, others against cuts, others against over-writing.

If you're looking for a representation that's best at surviving being printed, scanned and OCRed, then maybe a 1D or 2D barcode would be a better choice?

Answer (score 1):

Only one way to answer this question:  test it.  Create a set of samples for each letter, and run OCR on each sample.  The letters that OCR gets right the most often are the most "recognizable"; the letters that OCR gets wrong most often are the most "different".